# How to set up a cell of fetchedResultsController driven tableView when tableView is empty?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Hi I have a tableView where the fetchResultsController is the datasource.
When a object is added it adds it to the tableView, and when object gets deleted also the tableView adapts appropriate. All works fine.
But how can I set up a cell when the tableView is empty?
Lets say the cell should say "Press the refresh button." This cell should of course go away as soon as there are objects to display.

I have set up my tableView as following:

```
 // Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
        return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
        return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
 }


 // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
 }

 - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
        return [sectionInfo name];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you check whether your data source is empty in     numberOfRowsInSection and if it is add an element to `sectionInfo` that represents the 'refresh' cell before returning the size of the data source? You would have to remove that cell once you get valid data through though/

It might be cleaner to add a 'refresh' subview to your tableView when your dataSource is empty and remove it when it has > 1 element though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];

        if ([sectionInfo numberOfObjects] == 0) {
              return 1;
        }
        return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
 }

 // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.

    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section]; // get the list of items. Do it yourself

if ([sectionInfo numberOfObjects] == 0) {
    [cell.textLabel setText:@"Press the refresh button"];
}
else {
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
}
    return cell;
 }
```

---

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath =  [[NSIndexPath alloc] indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];  
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell.textLabel setText:@"Some Text"];  //Configure it with the first object you get
```

---

or

---

```
[listOfObjects removeAllObjects] // Remove all objects - set list count to 0.
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: I already tried that works perfect BUT it never goes away! and when other objects come in they are not displayed.

Comment: Do you reload the TableView when you get new data? If that too doesn't work, then the code snippets in the answer when you get new data.

Comment: no I do not reload the table view! data is updated in the NSFetchedResultsController delegates via insert,delete,....